# Trying to develop a custom application like Netdrive , ExpanDrive

Tags: node.js, windows, networking, desktop-application, webdav

I am trying to develop a windows desktop application  which should mount webdav share as a local disk (working eg: NetDrive , ExpanDrive , WebDrive). Could  anyone suggest me how should be my approach to achieve this. Does node, Electron-js are suitable to achieve this. correct me if i am in wrong direction.

Comment: Are you using the WebDAV protocol (Windows already supports it) or are you using custom protocols? Do you want to create a drive letter or just show up in the Explorer namespace?

Comment: yeah I want to assign a drive letter, and also i am aware of windows webdav mini redirector, but there is an issue with it, if we open any ms office document or pdf document then a prompt occurs asking for user credentials each and every time of access..